# HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am seeing this when i do ps -aef | grep elasticsearch
**HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError**

> 501 37347     1   0  2:29PM ttys004    0:04.14 /usr/bin/java -Xms4g
>   -Xmx4g -Xss256k -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=/Users/abdullahmuhammad/elasticsearch -cp :/Users/abdullahmuhammad/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-0.20.6.jar:/Users/abdullahmuhammad/elasticsearch/lib/*:/Users/abdullahmuhammad/elasticsearch/lib/sigar/*
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticSearch

I have tried a few things. Playing with the size of initial heap. Increasing, decreasing it.
I have also deleted my whole index but still i get no luck.

I used following to delete the index.

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/_all/'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am getting HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError.

Comment: HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError is not something you get. It's a JVM options   designated to take a heap dump on OOME

Answer (score 0):

If you use some plugins like Marvel you should check indexes count and their size. Because some plugins create big number of indixes and they can eat all your memory.

Answer (score 0):

For the heap, Elasticsearch recommands 50% of your available memory.
General, Elasticsearch recommandations for memory: max. 64GB, min. 8GB.

Important documentation:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hardware.html

Answer (score -1):

A few recommendations:
- Adjust your ES_HEAP_SIZE environment variable.
- Set mlockall option (in config file) of ES to true. This will always allocate a concrete block of heap memory.
- If your system is not very strong, you decrease your shard number. Note that; while increasing the number of shards increases the insert performance, increasing number of replication increases the query performance.